# Is a good practice bind view model with view controller using closure in MVVM pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, closures

I have an application in which the cell is removed from the collection view after a long press on it. Deletion occurs in the view model and it looks like this:

```
func deleteFood(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, completion: @escaping ([FoodBySections], [FoodBySections]) -> ()) {
    let objectToDeleteName = self.foodBySections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name!

    let oldData = foodBySections
    CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.deleteFoodFromFridge(foodName: objectToDeleteName)
    foods = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.fetchFoods()
    //newData
    foodBySections = FoodBySections.split(foods: foods!)
    //return data to view controller for collection view
    completion(oldData, foodBySections)
}
```

In the view controller code looks like this:

```
 @objc func deleteFood(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {
    if gesture.state != .ended {
        return
    }

    let point = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)

    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
        self.foodViewModel?.deleteFood(forIndexPath: indexPath, completion: { [weak self] (oldData, newData) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            //receive data from view model via closure
            self.collectionView.animateItemAndSectionChanges(oldData: oldData, newData: newData)
        })
    }
}
```

Is it a good practice? Or RxSwift is a good idea anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep the view separated from the dataSource and background functions that don’t do anything to the actual view it should be ok and it is good practice. In your case I’m not really sure where you are placing your functions but I’m guessing the action propagates all the way to the viewModel and then to the dataSource to delete the item. I have built a few apps using MVVM and it really is awesome, clean and easy to understand. My last app was using reactive, not exactly RxSwift but ReactiveSwift, they are pretty much the same anyway. To be honest if you have the time and patience to rewrite your app to rx, it is definitely a good idea, it really saved me a lot of time in delegating and observing but it is a bit more complex to grasp at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! I am placing my functions for interaction with Core Data in the class CoreDataHelper: NSObject. View Model using this class for changes data in Core Data. In my question this code is CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.deleteFoodFromFridge()